# How to get data in the axios header to a component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I have an axios `apiClient` and I'm trying to get the email stored in `localStorage` into the header.  In my component I tried using

```
response.headers['email']
```

and assigning it to an email variable but I'm getting undefined. I'm getting the email in `localStorage` but not able to get it in the component. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Axios

```js
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${API}`,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
     Accept: "application/json",
             "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
});

apiClient.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  let email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email'));
  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    config.headers.email = `${email}`;
  }
  return config;
}, function (err) {
  return Promise.reject(err);
});
```

Here is the method in my component where I need the email data

```js
methods: {
  getOrders(){
    service.getAllOrders()
    .then(response => {
      this.email = response.headers['email'];
      console.log("email:", this.email)
    })
  }
}
```

`getAllOrders()` does an axios `get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the *request* interceptor but you're checking the *response* header, and those are two different objects.  The response is from the server and won't be affected by a request interceptor.

You can create a different interceptor for the response:

```js
apiClient.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    response.headers.email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('email'));
    return response;
});
```